# How to parse an array within a query builder's get()

Tags: laravel

I have my Country model and a State Model. Only countries that have states can show states, or return [];

I would like to return this in one hit into my response object, yet I can't wrap my head around getting the id of the current country that is running in the query, I built this just now:

```
return response()->responseObject([
                'code'    => 200,
                'status'  => true,
                'message' => 'Retrieved List of Available Countries',
                'data' => Country::where('allow_registration', Country::REGISTRATION_ALLOWED)->get([
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    'iso',
                    'iso3',
                    'prefix',
                    'states' => function($query){}
                ])
            ]);
```

And I have another function waiting for this:

```
public static function getStates($id)
{
    $states = State::where('country_id', $id);
    return $states ? $states : [];
}
```

Am I approaching this right? What do I have to put in my sub query function in order for current country ID? Or did I approach this wrong and there is a **more eloquent way** of implementing?

Comment: does the 'countries' table have state_id and does the 'states' table have country_id?  If so I would route model bind and then return the property by creating a hasMany relationship.  If you'd like more specifics let me know but the answer below is literally on the right track, just not explained properly.

Comment: Hi there. Please try to avoid making gender assumptions about software engineers, as it can be unwelcoming. We tend to trim greetings and salutations anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in your `country` model create `states` relation

```
$this->hasMany(State::class);
```

then you can get all countries with its states by that :

```
Country::with('states')->get();
```

Comment: you gonna get downvoted really quick with that answer that doesn't address anything relevant to my question, I do appreciate your effort though, thanks Gamal.

Comment: what is your problem with this answer? @erezt